# Why does printing a Java array show a memory location

Tags: java, arrays

```
int[] answer= new int[map.size()];  
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();  

for (int j=0; j<answer.length;j++){  
    int x=map.get(keys.get(j));  
    answer[j]=x;  
}  

return answer
```

When I print `x` using `System.out.println(x)` in the loop, I get values of `1, 2, 3` but when I return the answer and print it, I get `[I@9826ac5`. Any idea why?

Comment: `return java.util.Arrays.toString(answer);`

Comment: It's not really a duplicate b/c the OP doesn't understand that he's even printing an array.

Answer (score 8):

Long story short, you can't easily print an array in java. Do this:

```
System.out.println( Arrays.toString(answer) );
```

Comment: I'd argue that's pretty easy. ;)

Answer (score 7):

`I[` is kind of the "class type" for an array of integer.  Printing out this array itself will print the class type `@` then a short hex string because that's the hash code of the array.  It's the same as something you've probably seen like `Object@0b1ac20`. This is implemented as the default [`toString()` for `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

Maybe you want to return a specific element of the array or print the whole array using a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

because that is how array's `toString()` method is implemented

Comment: duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array