# Converting a character array to a string

Tags: java

Why is the toString method returning jibberish?

```
char[] arrays = {'a','b','c'};
  { a, b, c }
arrays.toString()
  "[C@6519ceb1"
```

Comment: Is that really what it prints out?!

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why it's doing this. Is this normal or is the toString method not supposed to take arrays?

Comment: Yes, that's the default `toString()` returned from a char array. Instead do, `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arrays));`

Comment: And `new String(char[])` or `String.valueOf(char[]`) didn't help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does printing a Java array show a memory location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794930/why-does-printing-a-java-array-show-a-memory-location) ([simplest way to print an array in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java) )

Comment: @Hover Is there a method that would return "abc" rather than the full array?

Comment: by the way, if it works, it will not print `abc` which i assume you expect(refering to your question title), it will print `[a, b, c]`

Comment: @KevinDuke If you mean you want to construct a new string from the contents of the character array ... `String` already gives you that http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])

Comment: Hm, Mad's comment must be in invisible ink. ;)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Nah, I'm just invisible...I like to haunt here ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeing is the string representation of the array object as an `Object`. (The default behavior of `toString()` for all objects is to print a representation of the object reference. You cannot override that behavior for arrays.) To get a string representation of the *contents* of the array, you need to either pass the character array to a `String` constructor:

```
char[] arrays = {'a','b','c'};
String s = new String(arrays); // "abc"
```

or (depending on what you are trying to accomplish) use

```
String s = java.util.Arrays.toString(arrays); // "[a,b,c]"
```

Comment: +1, but shouldn't that be `array` rather than `arrays`? (Despite what OP might have coded?)

Comment: In that case,he's not getting a string (like a word) he's getting the string interpretation of an array, which doesn't seem like what he wants?

Comment: @Bohemian - OP's original code named the array `arrays`; I was just going with that. Personally, I would name such an array something less confusing (like `theArray` or `theChars`).

Comment: @developercorey - I don't know what OP wants, only that he doesn't want the default `toString()` behavior. (Incidentally, using `new String(arrays)` will produce exactly the same output as your code.)

Comment: @Bohemian are you referring to `java.util.Arrays.toString`? I believe it is `arrays`

Comment: @RafaEl no, the variable name `char[] arrays` is a stupid name - it's not many arrays, and *an* array, so the better name would be `char[] array`.

Comment: @Bohemian LOL you are definitely right. but some people doesn't really care about the naming

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] arrays = {'a','b','c'};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrays));
```

This is using java.util.Arrays
Implementation can be found

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29

By default it is using Object class's toString implementation

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```