# Generating random numbers giving the same number each time

Tags: java

My assignment:

> A simple random generator is obtained by the formula  `= ( ⋅
>    + )%`. New “random” numbers are then generated by setting
>    to  and repeating the process. Write a method
>   that asks the user to enter a value for , ,  and . Your
>   method should return an array of integers that contain the first 25
>   “random” values generated by this formula.

So far this is what I have, but for some reason my code is not printing the array of random 25 numbers

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner theInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a value for r: ");
        int r = theInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a value for a: ");
        int a = theInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a value for b: ");
        int b = theInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a value for m: ");
        int m = theInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println(random(r,a,b,m));

    }

    public static int[] random(int r, int a, int b, int m){
        String num = "";
        int numberArray[] = new int [25];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
            int answer = (a*r+b)%m;
            numberArray [i] = answer;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<numberArray.length;i++){
            System.out.println(numberArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        return numberArray; 
    }
```

This is what is printing:

```
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258
258

[I@55f96302
```

Can someone help me to fix the problem?

Comment: You haven't implemented this step: `New “random” numbers are then generated by setting   to  and repeating the process.`

Comment: You've not implemented it the way it calls for in the instructions. Read them again and investigate your code for the problem. The output is a dead giveaway.

Comment: So I fixed my code

Comment: public static int[] random(int r, int a, int b){
  String num = "";
  int numberArray[] = new int [25];
  for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
   int answer = (a*r+b);
   numberArray [i] = answer;
   r = answer;
  }
  for(int i=0;i<numberArray.length;i++){
   System.out.println(numberArray[i]);
  }
  System.out.println();
  return numberArray; 
 }

Comment: But it keeps printing the memory address of the array. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Passing an array to `System.out.println()` will print out the "memory address" of the array. You can use `Arrays.toString()` to get a nicely formatted `String` of the array contents:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(random(r,a,b,m)));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You get 25 same numbers is because you are using the same r for the same formula 25 times!

Instead, according to the assignment requirements, you should update the r as the newly generated random number and use it to generate the next random number!

2. You should use a for loop to print an array instead of `System.out.println(numberArray)`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794930/why-does-printing-a-java-array-show-a-memory-location) for more explanation.

For your reference:

```
public static int[] random(int r, int a, int b, int m) {
    String num = "";
    int numberArray[] = new int [25];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
        int answer = (a * r + b) % m;
        numberArray [i] = answer;
        r = answer;                // you should set r as the answer and use it for the next random number
    }
    return numberArray;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner theInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a value for r: ");
    int r = theInput.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a value for a: ");
    int a = theInput.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a value for b: ");
    int b = theInput.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a value for m: ");
    int m = theInput.nextInt();

    int[] numberArray = random(r, a, b, m);

    for(int i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++){
        System.out.println(numberArray[i]);
    }
}
```