# How to convert String variable back in byte[] in JAVA

Tags: java

I have the following code to zip and unzip the String:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String Source = "hello world";
    byte[] a = ZIP(Source);
    System.out.format("answer:");
    System.out.format(a.toString());
    System.out.format("\n");


    byte[] Source2 = a.toString().getBytes();

    System.out.println("\nsource 2:" + Source2.toString() + "\n");

    String b = unZIP(Source2);
    System.out.println("\nunzip answer:");
    System.out.format(b);
    System.out.format("\n");


}

  public static byte[] ZIP(String source) {
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos= new ByteArrayOutputStream(source.length()* 4);

      try {
          GZIPOutputStream outZip= new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
          outZip.write(source.getBytes());
          outZip.flush();
          outZip.close();
      } catch (Exception Ex) {
      }
      return bos.toByteArray();
  }

public static String unZIP(byte[] Source) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bins= new ByteArrayInputStream(Source);
    byte[] buf= new byte[2048];
    StringBuffer rString= new StringBuffer("");
    int len;

    try {
        GZIPInputStream zipit= new GZIPInputStream(bins);
        while ((len = zipit.read(buf)) > 0) {
             rString.append(new String(buf).substring(0, len));
        }
        return rString.toString();
    } catch (Exception Ex) {
       return "";
    }
}
```

When "Hello World" have been zipped, it's will become [B@7bdecdec in byte[] and convert into String and display on the screen. However, if I'm trying to convert the string back into byte[] with the following code:

```
 byte[] Source2 = a.toString().getBytes();
```

the value of variable a will become to [B@60a1807c instead of [B@7bdecdec . Does anyone know how can I convert the String (a value of byte but been convert into String) back in byte[] in JAVA?

Comment: This is not the value of the variable, it's its hashcode, like an identifier, use `Arrays.toString(byteArray)` to see the value

Comment: You need to use a character encoding like ISO 8859 1 for creating the String and getting the bytes.

Comment: Or, more likely, UTF-8: `str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` (you can make that more readable with a static import).

Comment: Rule of thumb: always assume the default platform encoding is something horrifying, like EBCDIC, and act accordingly.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794930/why-does-printing-a-java-array-show-a-memory-location

Answer (score 3):

Why doing `byte[] Source2 = a.toString().getBytes();` ?

It seems like a double conversion; you convert a `byte[]` to `string` the to `byte[].`

The real conversion of a `byte[]` to string is `new String(byte[])` hoping that you're in the same charset.

`Source2` should be an exact copy of `a` hence you should just do `byte[] Source2 = a;`

Answer (score 2):

Your unzip is wrong because you are converting back a string which might be in some other encoding (let's say UTF-8):

```
public static String unZIP(byte[] source) throws IOException {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(source.length*2);
  try (ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(source);
       GZIPInputStream zis = new GZIPInputStream(in)) {
    byte[] buffer = new buffer[4096];
    for (int n = 0; (n = zis.read(buffer) != 0; ) {
      bos.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
  }
  return new String(bos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

This one, not tested, will:

- Store byte from the gzip stream into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`
- Close the gzip/`ByteArrayInputStream` using try with resources
- Convert the whole into a `String` using UTF-8 (you should **always** use encoding and unless rare case, UTF-8 is the way to go).

You must not use `StringBuffer` for two reasons:

- The most important one: this will not behave well with multi bytes string such as UTF-8 or UTF-16.
- And second, `StringBuffer` is synchronized: you should use `StringBuilder` whenever possible and whenever it should be used (eg: not here!). `StringBuffer` should be reserved for case where your share the `StringBuffer` with several threads, otherwise it is useless.

With those change, you will also need to change the ZIP as per David Conrad comment and because the unZIP use UTF-8:

```
public static byte[] ZIP(String source) throws IOException {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(source.length()* 4);
  try (GZIPOutputStream zip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos)) {
    zip.write(source.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  }
  return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

As for the main, printing a `byte[]` will result in the default `toString`.